# Google Sheets: adjusting targetrange and adding conditon to sourcerange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script runs once per hour, and works to add new tickets to the "today" tab from the "Injection" tab (which is a importrange from another sheet that changes every 15 minutes). I would like to add 2 additional steps that I have been struggling with

1. The target range should be the next free row in the target sheet (Column G), currently it is a fixed value that would overwrite existing data. To further complicate things the target sheet is wiped clean every evening at 00:00, meaning the first free row reverts to G7.
2. The source range should only take values that have the text "New" in Column X, currently it pulls all values indiscriminately

Thanks in advance for any advice or support

```
    function tickets(){ 

var sourceSheet = "Injection" ;
var sourceRange = "A4:N504" ; 
var targetSheet = "Today" ; 
var targetRange = "G7:T507" ;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet); 
var values = sheet.getRange(sourceRange).getValues(); ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(targetRange).setValues(values); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function tickets(){ 

  const sourceSheet = "Injection" ;
  const targetSheet = "Today" ; 

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet); 
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet); 

  const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock()
    
  try{
    lock.waitLock(15000);
  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    const COL_X_INDEX = 23;
    const newValues = ssh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(row=>row[COL_X_INDEX]==='New');
    
    if(newValues.length>0){
        const lastRow = tsh.getRange('G:G').getDataRegion().getValues().length()
        const targetRange = tsh.getRange(lastRow+1,1,newValues.length, newValues[0].length)
        targetRange.setValues(newValues)
    }
  } finally{
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this works well the only thing is it needs to output to the first empty cell in Column G, as above it outputs at Column A.